# foreach() Loop Outputting Data and Creating Layout

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am currently trying to create a class schedule which I pull from my Sql Server database with PHP and I am trying to get the layout output as well as the data as I am grouping the resources.

These groupings are nested such as:

```
-DAY
--TIME
---CLASS
----STUDENTS
```

And should output like this:
[image]

However, I am getting this:
[image]

My current output is working, however, it is only on the first loop, then everything goes haywire. I am assuming there is an erroneous `</div>` tag somewhere in my code yet I cannot for the life of me find it.

My php code is a function that is delcare as such:

```
<div class="mainScheduleWrapper">
    <?php daySchedule(); ?>
</div>
```

My php code is as such:

```
function daySchedule() {
    global $conn;
    $dayScheduleQuery = 'SET DATEFIRST 1
                SELECT [DAY].[DAY] AS [DAY], CLASS.CLASSTIME AS CLASSTIME, CLASSLEVEL.CLASSLEVEL AS CLASSLEVEL, CLASS.MAXSTUDENT AS MAXSTUDENT, INSTRUCTOR.FIRSTNAME AS INSTRUCTOR, STUDENT.FIRSTNAME AS STUDENTFIRST, STUDENT.SURNAME AS STUDENTLAST, STUDENT.DOB AS STUDENTDOB
                FROM STUDENT JOIN BOOKING ON STUDENT.ID = BOOKING.STUDENTID JOIN CLASS ON CLASS.ID = BOOKING.CLASSID JOIN CLASSLEVEL ON CLASS.CLASSLEVELID = CLASSLEVEL.ID JOIN [DAY] ON CLASS.CLASSDAY = [DAY].ID JOIN INSTRUCTOR ON CLASS.INSTRUCTORID = INSTRUCTOR.ID
                WHERE   [DAY].ID = (DATEPART(dw, GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE \'AUS Eastern Standard Time\'))
                ORDER BY CLASS.CLASSTIME ASC, INSTRUCTOR.FIRSTNAME ASC, CLASSLEVEL.CLASSLEVEL ASC';

    // COUNTERS
    $t = 0;
    $i = 0;

    //VARIABLES FOR DAY SCHEDULE
    $classDay = NULL;
    $classTime = NULL;
    $classInstructor = NULL;
    $closeClass = false;
    $closeAll = false;
    $queryConnector = $conn->query($dayScheduleQuery);

    foreach ($queryConnector as $schedule) {

        // CLASS DAY HEADER
        if ($classDay != $schedule['DAY']) {

            echo '<div class="grid-1">';
            echo '<h1>' . $schedule['DAY'] . '</h1>';
            echo '</div><!-- Day closed! -->';
            $classDay = $schedule['DAY'];

        }

        // CLASS TIME HEADER
        if ($classTime != $schedule['CLASSTIME']) {

            if($classTime != $schedule['CLASSTIME'] && $t > 0) {
                $closeAll = true;
                goto closeAll;
            }

            echo '<div class="grid-12-noGutter scheduleContainer">'; //NON-CLOSED
            echo '<h1>' . 'T = ' .  $t . '</h1>';
            echo '<div class="grid-middle-center col scheduleTimeTab">';
                // FIX 3 DIGIT MILITARY TIME
                if (strlen($schedule['CLASSTIME']) < 4) {
                    $classScheduleTime = '0' . $schedule['CLASSTIME'];
                } else {
                    $classScheduleTime = $schedule['CLASSTIME'];
                }
                echo '<p>' . date('g:i A', strtotime($classScheduleTime)) . '</p>';
            echo '</div>'; //CLOSE TIME TAB

            echo '<div class="innerSchedule">'; // NON-CLOSED

            $classTime = $schedule['CLASSTIME'];
            $t += 100;

        }
        // INSTRUCTOR HEADER
        if ($classInstructor != $schedule['INSTRUCTOR']) {

            if ($classInstructor != $schedule['INSTRUCTOR'] && $i > 0) {
                $closeClass = true;
                goto closeClassWrapper;
            }

            echo '<div class="classWrapper">';
            echo '<h1>' . 'I =' . $i . 'T = ' .  $t . '</h1>';
                echo '<div class="grid-3-middle classHeader">';
                    echo '<div class="col classHeaderCell' . classLevelColour($schedule['CLASSLEVEL']) . '">' . $schedule['CLASSLEVEL'] . '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="col classHeaderCell">' . $schedule['INSTRUCTOR'] . '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="col classHeaderCell">Max' . ' ' . $schedule['MAXSTUDENT'] . '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="grid-4-middle" id="studentHeaders">';
                    echo '<div class="col"><h6>Student Name</h6></div>';
                    echo '<div class="col"><h6>Student Birthday</h6></div>';
                    echo '<div class="col"><h6>Class Level</h6></div>';
                    echo '<div class="col"><h6>Attendance</h6></div>';
                echo '</div>';

            $classInstructor = $schedule['INSTRUCTOR'];
            $i += 100;

        }
        echo '<div class="grid-4 studentRow">';
            echo '<div class="col">';
                echo '<span class="studentCell">' . $schedule['STUDENTFIRST'] . ' ' . $schedule['STUDENTLAST'] . '</span>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="col">';
                echo '<span class="studentCell">' . $schedule['STUDENTDOB'] . '</span>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="col">';
                echo '<span class="studentCell">' . $schedule['CLASSLEVEL'] . '</span>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="col">';
                echo '<span class="studentCell">--</span>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        // GOTO TAGS
        closeClassWrapper: {
            if ($closeClass === true) {
                echo '</div>';
                $closeClass = false;
                $i = 0;
            }
        }

        closeAll: {
            if ($closeAll === true) {
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                $closeAll = false;
                $t = 0;
                $i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - even if it's to tell me I'm going about it the completely wrong way.

Kindest Regards
Michael Z

Comment: Why are you building your layout with PHP, such bad idea

Comment: Could you give me any suggestions as to how I would build this structure from a database (that is always being updated) any other way?

Comment: sure, you need separation of concern, your view should just be an `HTML` file, then use `javascript` (`AJAX`) to make request to your server,  you should only use PHP to perform the query and return `JSON` data back to your client.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say you're going about it the *completely* wrong way, but a few red flags jumped out at me in your code.

1. The use of `goto` jumping is bad practice. It butchers your program flow and forces you to segregate tasks that shouldn't be kept apart. You marked the sections of code "// NON CLOSED" when there was a `</div>` missing, is there any purpose for that? How do you know the `goto` sections are reliable?
2. When you `echo` something like `<div class="col">`, without escaping the double-quotes (as in **\"** for every **"** character), it can be problematic. Your code can get mangled or misinterpreted, both on the PHP end or on the HTML end.

Like others have said, the use of PHP may be overkill here. Besides just sending the JSON, the rest could be handled with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! :) In regards to using JSON, the only time I have done this is when building a site for a client with Shopify and their templating system. Any tips on where I could find out how to achieve what I am doing with JSON??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php I know very little about JSON, this might help you though.

Comment: Hmmm... I have been looking a few things up and multidimensional arrays seem to be a good choice for this type of layout too.